# Explain the Behavior of the following JS code(Closures)

Tags: javascript, closures, iife

I want to know why there is such a weird behavior as variableOne should be same.

```
myfun = (function() {
            var variableOne = 10;
            get = function(){
            return variableOne;
            }
            set = function(value){
            variableOne = value;
            }
            return {variableOne,set,get};
            })();
        // Console Window Output
        console.log(myfun.variableOne);    
        >>10
        myfun.variableOne = 90;
        myfun.get()
        >>10
```

Why the value hasn't changed to 90 for variableOne.

Comment: Because you've changed the object property, not the variable.

Answer (score 0):

The ES6 shorthand object literal `{ variableOne }` creates an object property that *copies* the value from the local variable `variableOne`. Once copied, it lives a separate life. It does not give you access to the local variable.

If you want to keep a reference to the local value, you need to step away from a primitive variable, and use an object with the property `variableOne` instead. This way you don't copy its value into the property that is returned: it is now that property's value itself you return in the `get` method:

```js
myfun = (function() {
    return {
        variableOne: 10,
        get: function(){
            return this.variableOne;
        },
        set: function(value){
            this.variableOne = value;
        }
    };
})();
// Console Window Output
console.log(myfun.variableOne);    // 10
myfun.variableOne = 90;
console.log(myfun.get()); // 90
```

Using `get` and `set` as property names is not advised, since these are keywords in ES6. Instead use real getter/setters:

```js
myfun = (function() {
    return {
        _variableOne: 10,
        get variableOne() {
            return this._variableOne;
        },
        set variableOne(value) {
            this._variableOne = value;
        }
    };
})();
// Console Window Output
console.log(myfun.variableOne); // 10
myfun._variableOne = 90;
console.log(myfun.variableOne); // 90
```

Comment: This is not a destructuring assignment.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because `variableOne` is a Primitive value - primitive values are copied **by value**, not **by reference**, so once the assignment in the `return` (which is by the way creating properties by using the "object literal property value shorthand", not a destructuring assignment) is done, these are now two separate variables. On a side note - as I said, objects are copied by reference, but you still can change the reference itself by using assignment operator (you can read more about this in another SO question here: [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)).

What is more, the `get` method accesses the `variableOne` that is outside of the returned object - the one that was defined in the closure (it still lives on even though the closure has been already executed).

The `set` method is not actually a property setter, because creating a `setter` requires you to pass the property name. In this case, this is just another, regular object method.